# Word wrapping JLabel with <html> tag inside JScrollPane - Remove horizontal bar functionality/logic

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jscrollpane, jtextarea

My requirement is to do word wrapping (just like `JTextArea` does) with a `JLabel`.

Consider the following code:

```
public class WrapTest extends JFrame {

    public WrapTest() {
        super("test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
                + "Aliquam non pellentesque enim. Donec nec nisl tortor."
                + " Curabitur rutrum molestie est eget varius. Nullam ut lacinia est."
                + " Phasellus hendrerit sollicitudin justo, vitae malesuada dolor vestibulum at."
                + " Integer pharetra purus sed ipsum pulvinar, et pretium odio volutpat. Donec vitae varius metus."
                + " Cras sagittis vulputate erat, at faucibus lectus faucibus id. Cras varius nunc eu felis tristique dapibus."
                + " Aenean enim eros, dapibus pellentesque nibh ut, efficitur malesuada sapien. Nullam imperdiet nunc velit,"
                + "sed laoreet massa mattis eget. Morbi id justo quis sapien aliquet bibendum sed at leo. In mi felis, consectetur"
                + " sed orci eget, tempus maximus turpis. Curabitur sed felis id nisl vehicula sollicitudin sed eget erat.Ut sagittis at nisi sed facilisis."
                + " Morbi vel felis ac diam molestie consequat. Sed nisl lectus, sollicitudin at neque in, "
                + "placerat aliquet nunc. Maecenas quis enim vitae nunc fermentum congue. Sed posuere quam a ultricies fringilla."
                + " Vivamus aliquam nunc lacus, vitae consectetur tortor consequat ut. Cras viverra mi sit amet magna auctor eleifend."
                + " Morbi in risus nisl. Praesent nunc dolor, lobortis nec ultricies aliquet, sollicitudin eu sapien. Fusce interdum ac leo non suscipit."
                + "Vivamus at viverra elit, ut vestibulum elit. Sed bibendum, lorem et ornare sagittis, erat nulla ultricies odio, quis iaculis lacus nisl "
                + "vel ligula. Sed iaculis elit eu felis consectetur dignissim. ");

        add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setSize(500, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new WrapTest().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

The text is ugly and not readable. In order to make it better and add word-wrapping, let's add the `<html>` tag.

```
String wrap = "<html>";
label.setText(wrap + label.getText());
```

Word wrapping is ok, but when the size of the frame gets small, a vertical scroll bar is required to be able to read the text.
[image: preview]

Now let's try to add a `JScrollPane` and the label inside it:

```
String wrap = "<html>";
label.setText(wrap + label.getText());

JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(label);
add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

We have the following result:

[image: preview2]

Which again, makes the text unreadable. Using `sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);` will make the scroll bar disappear, and text remain horizontally - oriented.

Is there a way in this situation to remove the whole functionality of the horizontal bar? I want the label to be scrollable vertically with the word wrapping ability. Just like a `JTextArea` which behaves like:

[image: textarea]

The reason I insist to use a `JLabel` is the ease of rendering HTML tags.

I tried to solve it by changing the `preferredSize` and/or the `maximumSize` of the components, but I did not have the wanted result. Other things I tried is using `<body style='width:100%'>` or Xpx but they have another problems as well. As it makes sense, they are not being adjusted when frame gets bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is implement the `Scrollable` interface on the component that is added to the scroll pane.

Then you can force the component to fit the width of the viewport.

The easiest way to do this is to use the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/) which implements the methods of the `Scrollable` interface and allows you to customize the behaviour.

Then you add your label to the `ScrollablePanel` and the panel to the scroll pane:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class WrapTest extends JFrame {

    public WrapTest() {
        super("test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
                + "Aliquam non pellentesque enim. Donec nec nisl tortor."
                + " Curabitur rutrum molestie est eget varius. Nullam ut lacinia est."
                + " Phasellus hendrerit sollicitudin justo, vitae malesuada dolor vestibulum at."
                + " Integer pharetra purus sed ipsum pulvinar, et pretium odio volutpat. Donec vitae varius metus."
                + " Cras sagittis vulputate erat, at faucibus lectus faucibus id. Cras varius nunc eu felis tristique dapibus."
                + " Aenean enim eros, dapibus pellentesque nibh ut, efficitur malesuada sapien. Nullam imperdiet nunc velit,"
                + "sed laoreet massa mattis eget. Morbi id justo quis sapien aliquet bibendum sed at leo. In mi felis, consectetur"
                + " sed orci eget, tempus maximus turpis. Curabitur sed felis id nisl vehicula sollicitudin sed eget erat.Ut sagittis at nisi sed facilisis."
                + " Morbi vel felis ac diam molestie consequat. Sed nisl lectus, sollicitudin at neque in, "
                + "placerat aliquet nunc. Maecenas quis enim vitae nunc fermentum congue. Sed posuere quam a ultricies fringilla."
                + " Vivamus aliquam nunc lacus, vitae consectetur tortor consequat ut. Cras viverra mi sit amet magna auctor eleifend."
                + " Morbi in risus nisl. Praesent nunc dolor, lobortis nec ultricies aliquet, sollicitudin eu sapien. Fusce interdum ac leo non suscipit."
                + "Vivamus at viverra elit, ut vestibulum elit. Sed bibendum, lorem et ornare sagittis, erat nulla ultricies odio, quis iaculis lacus nisl "
                + "vel ligula. Sed iaculis elit eu felis consectetur dignissim. ");


        ScrollablePanel panel = new ScrollablePanel( new BorderLayout() );
        panel.setScrollableWidth( ScrollablePanel.ScrollableSizeHint.FIT );
        panel.add( label );

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(panel);
        add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setSize(500, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new WrapTest().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `JEditorPane` or `JTextArea` which you can disable editing and use them as a container to show your text with the desired line-wrapping.

But if you insist to use line-wrapping of `JLabel` and to support vertical scrolling, I believe you need to calculate the size of scrollable viewport container when the user resizes the frame:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class WrappedLabel implements Runnable {

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new WrappedLabel() );
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );

        String text = "Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
                + "Aliquam non pellentesque enim. Donec nec nisl tortor."
                + " Curabitur rutrum molestie est eget varius. Nullam ut lacinia est."
                + " Phasellus hendrerit sollicitudin justo, vitae malesuada dolor vestibulum at."
                + " Integer pharetra purus sed ipsum pulvinar, et pretium odio volutpat. Donec vitae varius metus."
                + " Cras sagittis vulputate erat, at faucibus lectus faucibus id. Cras varius nunc eu felis tristique dapibus."
                + " Aenean enim eros, dapibus pellentesque nibh ut, efficitur malesuada sapien. Nullam imperdiet nunc velit,"
                + "sed laoreet massa mattis eget. Morbi id justo quis sapien aliquet bibendum sed at leo. In mi felis, consectetur"
                + " sed orci eget, tempus maximus turpis. Curabitur sed felis id nisl vehicula sollicitudin sed eget erat.Ut sagittis at nisi sed facilisis."
                + " Morbi vel felis ac diam molestie consequat. Sed nisl lectus, sollicitudin at neque in, "
                + "placerat aliquet nunc. Maecenas quis enim vitae nunc fermentum congue. Sed posuere quam a ultricies fringilla."
                + " Vivamus aliquam nunc lacus, vitae consectetur tortor consequat ut. Cras viverra mi sit amet magna auctor eleifend."
                + " Morbi in risus nisl. Praesent nunc dolor, lobortis nec ultricies aliquet, sollicitudin eu sapien. Fusce interdum ac leo non suscipit."
                + "Vivamus at viverra elit, ut vestibulum elit. Sed bibendum, lorem et ornare sagittis, erat nulla ultricies odio, quis iaculis lacus nisl "
                + "vel ligula. Sed iaculis elit eu felis consectetur dignissim. ";
        JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>" +text+ "</html>");
        panel.add( label, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add( new WrappingScrollPane( panel ) );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize( 256, 256 );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}

class WrappingScrollPane extends JScrollPane implements ComponentListener {

    WrappingScrollPane( Container view ){
        super( view );
        this.viewport.addComponentListener( this );
    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden( ComponentEvent ce ){
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved( ComponentEvent ce ){
    }

    /** calculating required height is a 3 step process
      * 1. sync width of client and viewport, set height of client to high value
      * 2. let LayoutManager calculate required minimum size
      * 3. set preferredSize and revalidate
     **/
    @Override
    public void componentResized( ComponentEvent ce ){
        final Container view = (Container) this.viewport.getView();
        final int width = this.viewport.getExtentSize().width;
        view.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( width, Integer.MAX_VALUE ) );
        final int height = view.getLayout().preferredLayoutSize( view ).height;
        view.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( width, height ) );
        view.revalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown( ComponentEvent ce ){
    }
}
```

Comment: (1+). Good answer, but it needs "some fixes". **a)** The label needs to be in a nested panel. The line `view.getLayout()` will throw an `NPE` if the viewport contains the label and not a panel (`JLabel` has `null` layout). **b)** When the window appears, the scroll bar is not visible since the first resize. I will go with camickr's answer since I can use it somewhere else too. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. You pointed out the glitches completely right! It was just a late-night try to showcase the idea. The solution provided by camickr is far more general and cleaner than mine! I myself would go with camickr solution! ;-) Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);` ?

Otherwise you could try using a JEditorPane which has support for HTML content. This can then be placed in a JScrollPane.

Comment: Yes I have tried `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS`. You could try it yourself before posting it as an answer. Also, I am aware of `JEditorPane` but they are not so simple to use as `JLabel`.